# AWS Sagemaker groundtruthで1タスクに複数sourceを入れる場合のmanifestの編集方法

Tags: aws, json

AWS Sagemaker groundtruthで1ワーカーに複数音源のラベリングを実施してもらうタスクを作成したいと思っています。
以下のようにmanifestファイルを作成したいのですが、source-refで複数音源を指定することができません。
どのようにmanifestファイルを作成したら良いでしょうか？

dataset.manifest

```
 {"source-ref":["s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_01.wav", "s3://sagemaker-sample/audio_02.wav"]}
```

エラーメッセージ

> ClientError: Manifest: s3://sagemaker-sample/dataset.manifest has
>   invalid format at line number 0. Make sure that source or source-ref
>   field contains a string value